# F# `This expression was expected to have type 'IDictionary<Type,obj>' but here has type 'Dictionary<Type,obj>'

Tags: f#

I am trying to convert a [C# class](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/blob/master/src/Marten/Events/Projections/Aggregator.cs) into F#:

```ml
type Aggregator<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T)>()=
    static let ApplyMethod = "Apply"
    member val private _aggregations : IDictionary<Type, obj> = new Dictionary<Type, obj>()
    member val AggregateType = typeof<'T> with get
    member val Alias = Unchecked.defaultof<string> with get
```

However it seems that even this simple code cannot compile:

> `Program.fs`:1189 This expression was expected to have type
>       '`IDictionary<Type,obj>`'
>   but here has type
>       '`Dictionary<Type,obj>`'

Does it mean that a field declared with an interface `IDictionary<Type, obj>` type cannot infer the value passed knowing that this particular value implements that interface `Dictionary<Type, obj>`?

Actually if I am explicitely upcasting to `IDictionary<Type, obj>`:

```ml
member val private _aggregations : IDictionary<Type, obj> =
    (new Dictionary<Type, obj>() :> IDictionary<Type, obj>)
```

This works, does it mean that F# is stricter than C# in that regard?

Comment: Yes, F# requires explicit cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comment, F# does require an explicit:

```ml
type Aggregator<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T)>()=
    static let ApplyMethod = "Apply"
    member val private _aggregations : IDictionary<Type, obj> = new Dictionary<Type, obj>() :> IDictionary<Type, obj>)
    member val AggregateType = typeof<'T> with get
    member val Alias = Unchecked.defaultof<string> with get
```

Side notes:

- Btw, not everything what you can do in C# is possible in F# (no `protected` access modifier for example).
- Result of the conversion:

```ml
type Aggregator<'T when 'T : (new : unit -> 'T) and 'T : not struct> (overrideMethodLookup : IEnumerable<MethodInfo>)=
    let aggregations : IDictionary<Type, obj> = (new Dictionary<Type, obj>() :> IDictionary<Type, obj>) 
    let aggregateType = typeof<'T>
    let mutable alias = Unchecked.defaultof<string>
    do
        alias <-  typeof<'T>.Name.ToTableAlias();
        overrideMethodLookup.Each(fun (method : MethodInfo) ->
            let mutable step = Unchecked.defaultof<obj>
            let mutable eventType = method.GetParameters().Single<ParameterInfo>().ParameterType;
            if eventType.Closes(typedefof<Event<_>>) then
                eventType <- eventType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                step <- typedefof<EventAggregationStep<_,_>>.CloseAndBuildAs<obj>(method, [| typeof<'T>; eventType |]);
            else
                step <- typedefof<AggregationStep<_,_>>.CloseAndBuildAs<obj>(method, [| typeof<'T>; eventType |]);
            aggregations.Add(eventType, step)
        ) |> ignore

    static let ApplyMethod = "Apply"

    new() = new Aggregator<'T>(typeof<'T>.GetMethods()
                               |> Seq.where (fun x -> x.Name = ApplyMethod &&
                                                      x.GetParameters().Length = 1))

    member this.Add<'TEvent>(aggregation: IAggregation<'T, 'TEvent>) =
        if aggregations.ContainsKey(typeof<'TEvent>) then
            aggregations.[typeof<'TEvent>] <- aggregation
        else
            aggregations.Add(typeof<'TEvent>, aggregation)
        this

    member this.Add<'TEvent>(application: Action<'T, 'TEvent>) =
        this.Add(new AggregationStep<'T, 'TEvent>(application));

    interface IAggregator<'T> with

        member this.AggregatorFor<'TEvent>() =
            if aggregations.ContainsKey(typeof<'TEvent>) then
                aggregations.[typeof<'TEvent>].As<IAggregation<'T, 'TEvent>>()
            else
                null

        member this.Build(events, session, state) =
            events.Each(fun (x : IEvent) -> x.Apply(state, this)) |> ignore
            state

        member this.Build(events, session) =
            (this :> IAggregator<'T>).Build(events, session, new 'T());

        member this.EventTypes =
            aggregations.Keys.ToArray();

        member this.AggregateType =
            aggregateType

        member this.Alias =
            alias

        member this.AppliesTo(stream) =
            stream.Events.Any(fun x -> aggregations.ContainsKey(x.Data.GetType()));
```

Comment: I suggest you to start writing a blog about F#. I will follow it.

Comment: @NghiaBui actually I have a pretty big draft for post dedicated to the topic of learning F# for github.io pages ;-)

Comment: Note that you don't need to repeat the full type both in the annotation and the cast. You can either just put the cast and drop the annotation, or put the annotation and cast with `:> _`.